# how to auto-copy rows to new sheet VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy, spreadsheet

I'm trying to `auto-copy` a row from a `master` `spreadsheet` to another `spreadsheet`. This should occur when the input value in the `master` is equal to `X`.

So if `X` is entered into `Column A` in the `master`, then `auto-copy` to separate `spreadsheet` (let's call it X). Basically `Sheet X` should always contain an exact copy of all the `rows` in `master` where `Column A = X`.

I'm not sure if this would affect the `auto-copy` but the `master sheet` contains a `script` that hides/unhides `Columns`. So if `X` is entered into `Column A` in the `master sheet` then `Column B,C` will be hidden and `D,E,F` will be shown.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is shown below:

`Master Sheet` contains this info. But if `X` is entered into `Column A` only `D,E,F` will be visible

```
A B C D E F
X     4 5 6
Y 1 2 3 4 5
X     1 2 3
```

X Sheet:

```
A D E F
X 4 5 6
X 1 2 3
```

This is what I've attempted

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheets("Master")
Set sht2 = Sheets("X")

Intersect(sht2.UsedRange, sht2.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count)).ClearContents

sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, "X"
sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy sht2.Cells(2, 1)
sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

But it returns an Error:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic
Object variable with block variable not set
```

Comment: If `Intersect` returns `Nothing`, what object reference is `.ClearContents` invoked against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you start clearing "X" sheet from row 2 to preserve headers

should this be the case, you can clear all "X" sheet rows and paste headers form "Master" sheet back

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Master")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("X")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents
    Dim rng As Range

    With sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter 1, "X"
        For Each rng In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas ' loop through visible cells "groups"
            rng.Copy sht2.Range(rng.Address) ' copy current group and paste it to 'sht2' (i.e. sheet "X") corresponding address
        Next
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With sht2.UsedRange ' reference 'sht2' used range
        .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete ' delete referenced sheet blank rows
        .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete ' delete referenced sheet blank columns
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edited** to account for possible "Master" sheet hidden columns

Comment: Will it matter if the `master` sheet contain a `script` that hides/unhides columns based off a specific value being entered in `column A`? Your code returns an error: `That command cannot be used on multiple selections`.

Comment: The first line. `Sub FilterAndCopy()`

Comment: This cannot be. When you hit the error, click “debug” button and you’ll be brought to the offending line highlighted in yellow or blue

Comment: so from then on, step through your code by hitting F8 until you reach the actual offending line

Comment: Sorry. It's on the .SpecialCells line

Comment: see edited answer to handle any hidden column in "Master" sheet