# auto-copy rows to separate spreadsheet using VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy, autofilter

I'm trying to **auto-copy rows** from a worksheet to another worksheet when the input value in the first `Sheet` is equal to `Cat`.

So if `Cat` is entered into `Column A` in the `master`(first sheet), then auto-copy to A separate worksheet (let's call it `Cat`).

Basically, the sheet `Cat` should always contain an exact copy of all the rows in `master` where `Column A = Cat`.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is shown below:

**Master:**

```
A   B C D E F
Cat     4 5 6
Y   1 2 3 4 5
Cat     1 2 3
```

**Cat Sheet:**

```
A   D E F
Cat 4 5 6
Cat 1 2 3
```

**This is what I've attempted:**

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Master")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Cat")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    With sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter 1, "Cat"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy sht2.Cells(1, 1)
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

But there's an error in line:

```
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy sht2.Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: It looks like you're like you're just trying to use [AutoFilter](https://support.office.com/article/use-autofilter-to-filter-your-data-7d87d63e-ebd0-424b-8106-e2ab61133d92) programmatically.  Have you tried this manually (without VBA)?    Also, your example is using `X` to refer to worksheets, ranges, and values.  There are several other letters available in the alphabet, to help improve clarity of your question.

Comment: Auto filter could work but I need something to separate sheets. My master sheet contains a lot of various codes that need to be individualised for additional reporting purposes.

Comment: Happy to combine them @Comintern. I just posted two different methods for the same problem. Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you have to skip columns B and C, which [from your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732688/how-to-auto-copy-rows-to-new-sheet-vba-excel) I assume are hidden

then you can unhide columns B and C, copy/paste and then hide/delete them in those two sheets

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Master")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("X")

    sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents
    Dim rng As Range

    With sht1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Range("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns B and C
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter 1, "X"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht2.Cells(1, 1)
        .AutoFilter

        .Range("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns B and C
        sht2.Range("B:C").EntireColumn.Delete ' delete 'sht2' columns B and C
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way this code can work automatically without running the script each time X is entered into the Master sheet?

Comment: You can put a FilterAndCopy call inside a Worksheet_Change() event handler. My understanding is you’re already using such an event handler to hide some columns, so just add a line to it